# Join two table and get only those records where issue date is maximum for the issuer

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need help to get distinct records:

**Position table**

```
posid   |    issuerid
----------------------
```

**Other Table**

```
OtherID    |  issuerid   |   issue_date 
--------------------------------------
```

**I want**

```
OtherID    |  issuerid   |   Posid
--------------------------------------
```

Issue_date may be null for some issuer.
I want those other id, issuer id and posid where issue date is maximum if there is any for the issuer otherwise null

Comment: Provide some sample data, expected output, what you have tried and the results you had. No charity here..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT otherId, issuerId, posId
FROM (
    SELECT issuerId, MAX(ISNULL(issueDate,'17530101')) maxDate
    FROM otherTable
    GROUP BY issuerId
    ) M
JOIN otherTable O ON O.issuerId = M.issuerId AND O.issueDate = M.maxDate
JOIN positionTable P ON P.issuerId = M.issuerId
```

According to MS, the date 01/01/1753 is the minimum in a datetime field for SQL 2008. You can use any value of course as long as it's smaller than the smallest value in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OT.OtherID,PT.issuerid,PT.posid FROM [Position table] PT INNER JOIN [Other Table] OT ON PT.issuerid=OT.issuerid WHERE OT.issue_date IN
(SELECT MAX(issue_date) FROM [Other Table])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.orderid, a.issueid, b.posid
from other a, position b
where a.issueid=b.issueid
and (a.issuedate = (select max(c.issuedate) from other c where c.issueid = a.issueid)
or a.issuedate is null)
```